# Multiple rows with same ID return data from one column in only one if the rows sql 2

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT dbo.SalesOrder.SalesOrderID, dbo.SalesOrder.SalesOrderNo, dbo.SalesOrder.SubTotal, dbo.PO.PONo
FROM dbo.SalesOrder 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PO ON dbo.SalesOrder.SalesOrderID = dbo.PO.SalesOrderID
```

This shows the list of sales orders, their subtotal and connected po's.  When there are multiple po's connected to the same sales order it returns the subtotal for every po line.  I want it to only show the subtotal on the first line of that sales order.

[example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMkFC.jpg)

Comment: Can you share the table structure(basically primary and foreign key)

Comment: Show what you get now and what you want to get

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL Server 2012 you can use [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) to compare value with previous row. I use this to compare values to the previous row - I compare the `SalesOrderID` and `PreviousSalesOrderID` - if they differ you know to fill in the `SubTotal` column.

Solution:

```
SELECT SalesOrder.SalesOrderID, SalesOrder.SalesOrderNo, t1.PONo,
(CASE 
    WHEN (t1.PreviousSalesOrderID IS NULL) OR (t1.PreviousSalesOrderID <> SalesOrder.SalesOrderID) THEN SalesOrder.SubTotal
END) as SubTotal
FROM (SELECT SalesOrder.SalesOrderID, PurchaseOrder.PONo,
     LAG(SalesOrder.SalesOrderID) OVER (ORDER BY SalesOrder.SalesOrderID) AS PreviousSalesOrderID
     FROM SalesOrder LEFT OUTER JOIN PurchaseOrder ON SalesOrder.SalesOrderID = PurchaseOrder.SalesOrderID) AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesOrder ON SalesOrder.SalesOrderID = t1.SalesOrderID
```

Output (same as your expected output):

```
SalesOrderID    SalesOrderNo    PONo    SubTotal
8               S00008          p7      1544
9               S00009          p8      1644
9               S00009          p262    NULL
10              S00010          p263    4922
10              S00010          p9      NULL
11              S00011          p10     7805
```

Comment: GROUP BY groups the whole line though, I want each line separate, but the subtotal line to only show on the first line of that ID

Comment: I only have SQL Server 2008, is there an equivalent for 2008?

Comment: It is possible: [LAG and LEAD for SQL Server 2008](https://sqlscope.wordpress.com/2014/05/26/lag-and-lead-for-sql-server-2008/)